# how to write a constructor to initialize a set of pointers

Tags: c++, g++

let's assume that I have some codes like this. What should I write there in order to have a constructor that initializes a Foo typed object. Thanks. this is the example I am trying to understand `http://flylib.com/books/en/2.674.1.140/1/` sorry for the delay.

```
class Foo
{
private:
   set<int*> numbers;
public:
   //constuctor
   Foo(set<int*>& numb = "what to write here?"): numbers("something") {};

};
```

Comment: can you tell us more about your purpose?

Comment: Why are you taking the parameter by non-const reference?

Comment: One thing you need to really think about is that a set is not a useful container of pointers... set's are used to ensure you have a single instance of any given value (and you can use it for guaranteeing the ordering of those elements).  But raw pointers are in general a poor idea (unless you truly have a specific reason for them, know what that means, etc., etc.).  But in a set - a set of pointers?  Hard to fathom a valid purpose?

Comment: sorry for the delay. It's just a question in the book I am reading. they use set<string*>. I want to know if there's a way to initialize it in a constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley `http://flylib.com/books/en/2.674.1.140/1/` this is the problem I am trying to understand. Just trying to get the concept donne

Comment: for memory leaking problem. There's another function in the destructor that destroys dangling pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a set of pointers usually isn't what you want. sets are a collection of unique items, but a set of pointers means each pointer will be unique, not the values they point to.

Steve Jessop points out some more reasons not to want a container of pointers. For one, it's not clear who owns the pointers at what point, and so it's not clear how to handle errors. Part of sorting that out could mean imposing stricter requirements on the pointers, for example requiring them to be new allocated so that the object taking ownership knows how to release them. Such requirements will probably only be enforced by manual inspection of the code and documentation, and so will be error prone. That could be improved on by using smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

But if for some reason you really do want this with raw pointers, then:

```
   Foo(set<int*> const &numb = set<int*>()): numbers(numb) {}
```

Or use overloading instead:

```
   Foo() {} // default constructs numbers
   Foo(set<int*> const &numb) : numbers(numb) {}
```

Or if you really want to construct numbers as a non-empty set by default you can do the following (dangerous, leak prone) things:

```
   Foo(set<int*> const &numb = set<int*>()) : numbers(numb) {
       if(numbers.empty()) { // this also prevents the user from being able to make the set empty
           numbers.insert(new int(0));
           numbers.insert(new int(0));
       }
   }
```

Or using C++11:

```
   Foo(set<int*> const &numb = set<int*>{new int(0),new int(0)} ) : numbers(numb) {} // uses default argument value with brace initializer list style
```

or

```
   Foo(set<int*> const &numb) : numbers(numb) {}
   Foo() : Foo(set<int*>{new int(0),new int(0)}) {} // uses delegating constructors
```

Fixing the leaks above using smart pointers yields something like:

```
   Foo(set<unique_ptr<int>> const &numb = set<unique_ptr<int>>()) : numbers(numb) {
       if(numbers.empty()) { // this also prevents the user from being able to make the set empty
           numbers.insert(unique_ptr<int>(new int(0)));
           numbers.insert(unique_ptr<int>(new int(0)));
       }
   }
```

Using brace initialization with smart pointers like the following still has the possibility for leaks:

```
   Foo(set<unique_ptr<int>> const &numb = set<int*>{unique_ptr<int>(new int(0)),unique_ptr<int>(new int(0))} ) : numbers(numb) {}
```

So instead you should use a helper function to produce the default value:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    set<unique_ptr<int>> numbers;
    static set<unique_ptr<int>> default_set() {
        set<unique_ptr<int>> the_default;
        the_default.insert(unique_ptr<int>(new int(0)));
        the_default.insert(unique_ptr<int>(new int(0)));
        return the_default;
    }
public:
    // using default arg
    Foo(set<unique_ptr<int>> &&numb = default_set()) : numbers(move(numb)) {};

    // or delegating constructors
    Foo(set<unique_ptr<int>> &&numb) : numbers(move(numb)) {};
    Foo() : Foo(default_set()) {}

    // in addition to one of the above you probably want a constructor that takes a non-rvalue-reference and copies it
    Foo(set<unique_ptr<int>> numb) : Foo(move(numb)) {}; // copy is implicit, we delegate moving that copy into number to the ctor that takes an rvalue-reference. You could also just initialize numbers here directly.

};
```

Comment: For your 3rd solution, that could be a problem if the caller actually passes an empty set because that's what they want.

Comment: Yeah, but if the class has an invariant that the set can never be empty this enforces it. It depends on what the class is supposed to do.

Comment: General note, beware calling `new` twice in a row like that -- if the second one throws then the first is leaked. Similarly if `insert` throws then the allocation is leaked. In this case we haven't established who owns the pointers (and is responsible for freeing them) anyway, so it's anybody's guess how to sort out the mess, which is another common problem with a container of pointers.

Comment: @bames53 this is what I want. 
 
if I have a constructor like this (not for this problem). `Foo(const string* = ""): name(string) {}` this constructor would work on both `Foo var` and `Foo var("hello world")` right? I am trying to do something like this. instead of having two constructors. Someone mentioned non const-reference. Does it have something to do in this problem? it just means the object is const and the reference is not, right?

Comment: Assuming you mean `Foo(const char *str = "")` yes, that would allow both `Foo var` and `Foo var("...")`. Functions taking non-const references (e.g., `Foo(std::string &)` vs. `Foo(const std::string&)`) have a practical difference besides just that the object is const. It also means that you cannot call that function with a temporary, because temporaries cannot bind to non-const references. For example, with `Foo(std::string &)` the call `Foo("Hello")` will not compile.

Comment: @bames53 yes. I understand it now. Is there a possible way to have a constructor that takes a const reference set<*string> and could allow both `Foo Var` and `Foo var(set<*string>)` and doesn't have dangling pointers problem (the only way I can think of is that to have a function in destructor that removes danglings). thanks

Comment: I'm not sure which you mean by `*string` because this does not name a type. `std::string*`, or `char const *`? I would recommend using just `set<std::string>`: `Foo(set<string> const &s = set<string>())` or `Foo() : Foo(set<string>()); Foo(set<string> const &);`

Answer (score 4):

A non-const reference parameter cannot have an object as a default value, so the only thing you can write in "what to write here?" is a reference to a `set<int*>`. This means you'd have to have one lying around somewhere.

Probably you should instead write something like this:

```
class Foo {
    std::set<int*> numbers;
  public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const std::set<int*> &numb) : numbers(numb) {}
    // maybe this too
    template <typename InputIterator>
    Foo(InputIterator start, InputIterator end) : numbers(start,end) {}
};
```

This will initialize the set empty if a `Foo` is constructed with no args.

Btw, I can't think of many uses for a `set<int*>`, and none of them are simple.

Comment: if I have a constructor like this (not for this problem). `Foo(const string* = ""): name(string) {}` this constructor would work on both `Foo var` and `Foo var("hello world")` right? I am trying to do something like this. instead of having two constructors.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you're taking the parameter by non-const reference, so until I hear the reason for that, I'll ignore it.

If you want an empty set, you can do this:

```
Foo(const set<int*>& numb = set<int*>()): numbers(numb) {}
```

Of course, there's not much point to that, as you could just write a no-parameter constructor and let numbers have it's default value.  If you want it with some initial values, then write a function that populates one:

```
set<int*> make_numbers() { ... }
Foo(const set<int*>& numb = make_numbers()): numbers(numb) {}
```

Comment: for a non-const reference. I am thinking that this constructor would work on both `Foo var` and `Foo var(set<int*>)`

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
static int *arr[] = { new int(1), new int(2), new int(3) };

class Foo {
private:
std::set<int*> numbers;
public:
Foo(const std::set<int*>& numb = std::set<int *>(arr, arr + (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])))): numbers(numb) {}
};
```

Note about memory usage:
1)This code just demonstrate how to use default arg of type std::set. So I try to write the smallest code as possible for init array of pointers, and make this pointers valid.
Of course, the real program should not contain such code:

```
static int *arr[] = { new int(1), new int(2), new int(3) };
```

2)There are only 3 allocations, and number of them not depend on amout of objects of type Foo. And all this memory will be freed at end of program. And tools like valgrind will mark them as possibly lost, not definetly lost memory.

Comment: You realize that this code is full of memory leaks?!  This is not something you'd ever normally want to do.

Comment: @Mordachai: it allocates 3 `int` objects that aren't freed. That's 3 total, regardless of how many instances of class `Foo` you create, so it's hardly "full". OK, it's true that memory debugging tools will report then as unfreed blocks on program exit, and hence as potential leaks, but they aren't actually leaked, they're always accessible via `arr`.

Comment: @SteveJessop fair enough.  In this instance, only 3 ints are being lost (plus overhead).  But this *kind* of code is horrible.  And smacks of not understanding the issues underlying why do this in the first place.

Comment: If you default construct more than one Foo you'll have shared pointers. If you then deallocate the pointers for one of those then you'll have dangling pointers in the other. If you deallocate the pointers in the other set then you'll be double deleting.